# Schema with auto increment based on 2 columns and partially unique boolean

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, auto-increment, rdbms

There are 3 tables: **User**, **Thing**, **ThingUse**.

**Thing** can be `active` and `inactive`.
A single **User** can have many things but only one can be `active` at the time. Once Thing becomes `inactive` it cannot be activated again.
User can use `active` Thing which should result in the creation of **ThingUse** with its own unique thing useId.
I should probably note that eventually there will be millions if not billions of **ThingUse**'s

#### Example:

1. `user1(id: 1)` creates a `thing_1(id: 1, owner: 1, active: true)`
2. `user1` uses `thing_1` which results in `thing_use_1(id: 1, thingId: 1, useId: 1)`
3. `user1` uses `thing_1` which results in `thing_use_2(id: 2, thingId: 1, useId: 2)`
4. `user1` creates a `thing_2(id: 2, owner: 1, active: true)`, now `thing_1` should become `thing_1(id: 1, owner: 1, active: false)`
5. from now on `thing_1` is unactive and can no longer be used/reactivated
6. `user1` creates a `thing_use_3(id: 3, thingId: 2, useId: 1)` <- notice `useId` has been set to **1**
7. `user1` creates a `thing_use_4(id: 4, thingId: 2, useId: 2)`
8. `user2(id: 2)` creates a `thing_3(id: 3, owner: 2, active: true)`
9. `user2` creates a `thing_use_5(id: 5, thingId: 3, useId: 1)` <- notice `useId` has been set to **1**

At this point DB should look like:

```
user_1(id: 1)
    thing_1(id: 1, owner: 1, active: false)
        thing_use_1(id: 1, thingId: 1, useId: 1)
        thing_use_2(id: 2, thingId: 1, useId: 2)
    thing_2(id: 2, owner: 1, active: true)
        thing_use_3(id: 3, thingId: 2, useId: 1)
        thing_use_4(id: 4, thingId: 2, useId: 2)

user_2(id: 2)
    thing_3(id: 3, owner: 2, active: true)
        thing_use_5(id: 5, thingId: 3, useId: 1)
```

Other notes:

- Every **ThingUse** within single **Thing** should have unique (auto incremented) useId.
- If this wasn't obvious from above example relations between **User** to **Thing** and **Thing** to **ThingUse** are both one to many.

So basically there are 2 problems:

#### Problem A:

Single **User** can have only 1 `active` **Thing** at the time. From what I've read it's not possible in MySQL to create a special boolean row that allows single `TRUE` and multiple `FALSES`. However, I came up with 2 "workarounds". They both seem a little bit hacky though so maybe there are better solutions:

1. Create `uniqueIndex(owner, active)` on **Thing** and use `true`/`null` as `active`/`inactive` flags since MySQL doesn't treat nulls as a duplicated values.
2. The second idea is to treat the most recent user **Thing** as `active`. The problem in this case is that it's not 100% straightforward to what is going on + I assume it's going to be hard/slow to write a queries like `find all active things across all users`.
3. (Added on **@Edit1**) Third idea is to remove `active` column from **Thing** and add `activeThingId` column to **User** table. This way it won't be possible for single user to have multiple active things at the same time and it will be easy to query "all active things".

#### Problem B:

A single **Thing** cannot have multiple **ThingUse**'s with the same useId. To achieve that I can set `uniqueIndex(thingId, useId)` on **ThingUse**. That will prevent an accidental useId duplicates. However, there is still a problem with obtaining correct next useId/setting it. I could technically code this logic on the app level but I would rather have DB handle it for me if possible.

(Added on **@Edit2**)

Thanks, @JairSnow, I managed to partially solve **Problem B** using a trigger based on your procedure:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
    BEFORE INSERT ON ThingUse
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET @actual_value = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ThingUse WHERE thingId=NEW.thingId);
        IF (@actual_value IS NULL) THEN
            SET @actual_value = 0;
        END IF;
        SET NEW.useId=@actual_value;
    END
```

However, I had to use `COUNT(*)` instead of `MAX(useId)` because for some reason with the latter I was getting duplicated `useId`.

The only problem now is that if I add `ThingUse`'s quickly ex. without waiting for other/previous queries to finish I get a scary deadlock error: `ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.

**@Edit1**: added A.3.

**@Edit2**: partially resolved *Problem B*.

Comment: You could have 2 tables, 1st for Thing 2nd for ThingUse containing foreign key of the 1st.. In ThingUse you could add a column for active (per user) and last modified date for sorting.. Then add other columns as needed..

Comment: I am not 100% I understand your approach. I already have these 2 tables (**Thing** and **ThingUse**) and **ThingUse** contains *thingId*.


Regarding the second part of the answer: the thing is (:D) only **Thing** can be *active* or *inactive*, not **ThingUse**. Once **ThingUse** gets inserted into DB it never gets updated etc.

Comment: My approach is to use table values instead of table properties..

Answer (score 3):

Since in MYSQL the triggers cannot let you edit the same table that is triggered, I suggest to use some stored procedure to insert the data and do the action that you need.

Through this method although you have to use only the stored procedure and don't use query to manually add or update records to the table. (you can limit the add/update query with some triggers eventually if you want)

For **problem A** you can do something like that:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_new_thing`(IN `owner` INT)
begin
    INSERT INTO Thing(owner, active) VALUES(owner, 1);
    UPDATE Thing SET active=false WHERE owner=owner AND active=1 AND id != LAST_INSERT_ID();
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

For the **problem B** you can do something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `use_thing`(IN `thing_id` INT)
begin
    SET @actual_value = (SELECT max(useId) FROM ThingUse WHERE thingId=thing_id);
    IF (@actual_value IS NULL) THEN 
        SET @actual_value = 0; 
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO ThingUse(thingId, useId) VALUES(thing_id, @actual_value+1);
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note**: For the solution of the **problem B** note that that the number is always unique (because if you take the max number and do a +1 is unique by logic) but is not autoincrement (if you create a new record and is useId is 17, you delete that new record and create another record the useId of the last record would be 17 again)

**@Edit**: Optimized query of *problem A*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I partially managed to solve **Problem B** using a trigger based on your procedure. Updated main post if you want to have a look.